# How can I change a variables value from an async block without taking ownership of it

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I'm pretty new to rust, trying to make a small game with web assembly using rust and wasm-bindgen.
I have an event listener which listens for key presses, and returns a direction through a Stream.
Then I want to draw something to a canvas element every 500ms, based on the value of the direction variable.

My problem is that I'm unable to mutate the `direction` variable from the async block,
and use it in the Interval closure.

Using the `move` keyword in both the async block and the Interval closure makes the code compile,
but the direction is then never changed inside the interval function.
I think the direction variable is then copied into the block/closure, as the `Direction` enum implements the `Copy` trait.

I've included a simplified version of my entry point function:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn run() -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    let mut direction = Direction::Right;

    let fut = async {
        let mut on_key_down = EventListenerStruct::new();

        while let Some(dir) = on_key_down.next().await {
            direction = dir;
          // ^^^^^^^^ this errors because direction does not live long enough
          // argument requires that `direction` is borrowed for `static`
        }
    };
    spawn_local(fut);

    Interval::new(500, || {
        // I want to use direction here
    })
    .forget();

    Ok(())
}
```

My question is; Can I mutably borrow a variable into an async block?
And can I make it live long enough without taking ownership of it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using Arc and Mutex.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let mut direction = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Direction::Right));

    let direction2 = Arc::clone(&direction);
    let fut = async {
        let mut on_key_down = EventListenerStruct::new();

        while let Some(dir) = on_key_down.next().await {
            *direction2.lock().unwrap() = dir;
        }
    };
    spawn_local(fut);

    Interval::new(500, || {
        let direction = direction.lock().unwrap();
    })
    .forget();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully.

I did add a `move` keyword to the async block,
to prevent a compilation error "direction2 does not live long enough",
but the `direction` variable was still updated for the `Interval`.